# Alias in bash to Change Directory

Tags: terminal, bash, alias

When I am typing in a typical alias with my .bash_profile, my change directory is not working.

I currently have the following:

```
alias cdicloud="/Users/<username>/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Folder1/subFolder
```

Does anyone know how to properly change directories via an alias. All my other aliases work, but this one doesn't want to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape/protect any spaces etc in the path:

```
alias cdicloud="cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"
```

Executing this in Terminal looks like the following:

```
pse@Mithos:~$ alias cdicloud="cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs"
pse@Mithos:~$ cdicloud 
pse@Mithos:~/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs$ cd -
/Users/pse
pse@Mithos:~$
```

Comment: When I enter that, I get a No such file or directory error, as it is removing the / after Documents.

Comment: @CrashBurner Strange, I copied this directly from my own `.bash_profile`.  What does `type cdicloud` say?

Comment: It says: `cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents\com~apple~CloudDocs/F1/F18`. Yet in my alias, it reads exactly as follows: `alias cdicloud="cd ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/F1/F18"`

Comment: Your addition to the initial response worked. Thank you!